# GitHub Actions - Have Checkout action in its own job

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to configure a workflow in GitHub Actions using a self-hosted runner.

The runner itself has Node installed for the checkout task, but not Python, hence why I'm trying to run the python script inside the specified container. I'm trying to execute a simple Python script from inside the repo, however, when the second job runs inside the container, it cannot find the file main.py.

```yaml
name: GitHub Actions Test
on:
   workflow_dispatch:
     inputs:
       job:
         description: 'checkout and run'
         required: true
         default: 'checkout-repo' 
jobs:
  checkout-repo:
      runs-on: self-hosted
      steps:
        - name: Checkout
          uses: actions/checkout@v3
          
  run-python:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    container: 
      image: <some_python3_docker_image>
      credentials:
        username: ${{ github.actor }}
        password: ${{ secrets.github_token }}
    steps:
      - run: python3 main.py
```

Is there any way to make the repo workspace persist between the two jobs?

Comment: Why not using the `actions/checkout@v3` directly on the `run-python` job in a step  before running the script?

Comment: Because the checkout job then fails due to the container image not having node installed :(

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option to add node to the container? To run the script you'll need to perform the checkout first in the same job, otherwise the runner won't have access to the repository files (you could also install node and python in your self-hosted runner directly)

Comment: Seems like a lot of extra added bulk to the python3 docker image though, if its only purely used to checkout, is there absolutely no way to share the repo that's been checked out between jobs?

Comment: It's because each job start a new instance, so you would need artifact to share datas between them if you want to access the files. Another option to persist datas on the self-hosted runner would be to clone it there directly.

Comment: I don't think you need node in order to checkout a repository inside a container. Can you please share the error message? From what I remember, you either need `git` or it is going to use the REST api to download the contents, which probably needs some ssl libraries etc..

Comment: In fact I suspect the checkout (i.e. the thing that runs the `actions/checkout` action) is the runner and **not** your python image. Your runner not having node is practically impossible given that it comes packaged with the runner.

Comment: No just to clarify, the runner itself (a linux virtual machine) has node installed, the image which runs the python code does not (the docker image is a CentOS image with python3 installed and some other custom python config). You are correct, the checkout actually works because its not running in the specified image, but then the next stage can't find the repo files. However, when both stages are combined to use the container, the checkout fails because the image does not have node installed